# BackgroundSize is not working after background image has changed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a really really basic image slideshow. I just change to background image to whatever image is chosen. But when I change the image for the first time, the `backgroundSize: cover` seems to be gone. And when I change it again it also does not come back. I really dont understand this behaviour...

Here is a link to my code on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wihf2

And here is the link to the demo: https://angular-3wihf2.stackblitz.io

It also does not work, when I add a css class with `background-size: cover`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change,

```
[ngStyle]="{height: height + 'px', background: 'url(' + shownImage.path + ') no-repeat center center', backgroundSize: 'cover'}"
```

to

```
[ngStyle]="{height: height + 'px', background: 'url(' + shownImage.path + ') no-repeat center center / cover'}"
```

`backgroundSize` is not a valid property, instead you can give `background-size` value inside the `background` property itself by a forward slash `/` to separate from the position (`center`) value.

> [**Forked Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3jit6)

Comment: Thank you so much!